# Return Hibernate list data to struts success page

Tags: hibernate, struts

I am creating a project in which I am making user login with hibernate and I want to return user details to struts success page... I am integrating hibernate with struts here.
My User DAO method for login user

```
public List<User> userLogin(User user)
{
    boolean result;
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    String SQL="select * from stackoverflowUser where userEmail=? and userPassword=?";  // native query
    Query query=session.createSQLQuery(SQL);
    query.setParameter(0, user.getUserEmail());
    query.setParameter(1, user.getUserPassword());  query.setParameter("UPassword", user.getUserPassword());

    List<User> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

Login Action Class with execute method

```
public String execute()
{
    UserDAO list =new UserDAO();
    if (list.userLogin(user) != null)
    {
        return "success";
    }
    else
    {
        request.setAttribute("error","Sorry you are entering wrong Email Id or Password.");
        return "error";
    }
```

I want User data print over struts success page or welcome page

Comment: How can anyone help you without the code?

Comment: The list needs to be exposed as a property of the action. Then you're done. This is in every S2 tutorial ever.

Comment: can you do it for me

Comment: *Can* I? Yes. *Will* I? No. I mean, come on: make an action instance variable, expose it with a getter, done. I'd *strongly* recommend maybe looking at even a *single* S2 tutorial: how to expose data to a JSP page is pretty much the first thing shown in every single one--you need like four lines of code: the instance variable and the getter. I'm (somewhat) confident you can do that.